# LARAVEL FatalErrorException in default User model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

after login with default `User` model i get this error:

```
        Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

        Class User contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract 
        or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberToken, 
        Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::setRememberToken,
        Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberTokenName)
```

User:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

this version of Laravel :

```
Laravel Framework version 4.1.29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a composer update - and upgraded to 4.1.29 from a version below 4.1.26. In 4.1.26 there were some 'breaking' changes to the User model due to a security issue.

[You need to follow these upgrade instructions to fix the problem.](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26)

1. First, add a new, nullable remember_token of VARCHAR(100), TEXT, or equivalent to your users table.
2. Next, if you are using the Eloquent authentication driver, update your User class with the following three methods:

   ```
   public function getRememberToken()
   {
       return $this->remember_token;
   }

   public function setRememberToken($value)
   {
       $this->remember_token = $value;
   }

   public function getRememberTokenName()
   {
       return 'remember_token';
   }
   ```